# how to access php web service with Jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, cordova

I have a login webservice and i am try to access using Jquery Ajax. but i am not able to access.
I have use many method but not success. please my help

1. using  getJSON

   ```
   $("#login").click(function () {
       var url = 'http://localhost:8080/vrm/web_services/login?data=[{"email":"gaurav.gautam@mailinator.com","password":"123456","device_token":"GLKOS58GDG549853JSFJSBMSMSG"}]';
       jQuery.getJSON(url+"&callback=?", function(data) {
       alert("Success" + data.id);
   });
   ```
2. using .ajax()

   ```
   var markers = [{ "email": "gaurav.gautam@mailinator.com", "password": "123456","device_token":"GLKOS58GDG549853JSFJSBMSMSG" }]
   $.ajax( {
     //  url: 'http://localhost:8080/vrm/web_services/login?data=[{"email":"gaurav.gautam@mailinator.com","password":"123456","device_token":"GLKOS58GDG549853JSFJSBMSMSG"}]',
     uri:'http://localhost:8080/vrm/web_services/login',
     type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "jsonp",
       data:  JSON.stringify({ data: markers }),
       processdata:true,
       jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
       success : function(data) {

          var json = $.parseJSON(data);
          $('#items').html(json);
          alert(json);

       },
       error : function(req, status, ex) {

         alert("Lol" + ex);

       }
       });
   ```

I have also use dataType: "json" but not getting request.status 0
and when use dataType: "jsonp" getting error 'invalid label'

Comment: If you are using the jsonp data type with jQuery, you don't necessarily have to specify the callback since one would be generated for you. Might make your debugging a little easier. Also, the content type should be set by the server.

Answer (score 0):

For one, if you specify dataType: "json" then you don't need the `$.parseJSON(data)` call in there, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON and `data` will be a JavaScript object (on success, of course).

I recommend using either Firebug in Firefox or Safari or Chrome's developer tool (In Safari, go to Preferences, Advanced, check "Show Develop menu in menu bar".  Then Develop menu -> Show Error Console).  Then you can insert logging statements like `console.log(data)` to see what you got back, or look for errors printed in the console.  You can also go to the network tab in the developer inspector to watch what's being sent across the wire.  This should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: when use dataType: "jsonp" getting error 'invalid label' and when use dataType: "json" getting HTPP Code: 0 please help i have try last 2 day

Answer (score 0):

ajax is not allow cross-domain..

i have 1 way to solve this question:

created a script tag with js,like this:

```
var sc=document.createElement('script');
var url="http://localhost:8080/vrm/web_services/login?data=[{"email":"gaurav.gautam@mailinator.com","password":"123456","device_token":"GLKOS58GDG549853JSFJSBMSMSG"}]";
sc.setAttribute('src',url);
document.body.appendChild(src);
```